# Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be long,

Tags: php, cookies

i am trying this code:

```
setcookie('email', $first_email, 'hash', $this->hash, 'logout', $this->log, time()+60*60*24*100);
```

but i got: `Warning: setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be long,`

I want `setcookie` with multiple variables. How can be done ? maybe an array ?

Then i will have something like this, that is compared with values in database

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['email']) || empty($_COOKIE['hash']) || empty($_COOKIE['logout'])) {
    //something
}
else
//db
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign 3 different cookies in one function call. You need to set each cookie individually, as can be seen below:

```
setcookie('email', $first_email, time()+60*60*24*100);
setcookie('hash', $this->hash, time()+60*60*24*100);
setcookie('logout', $this->log, time()+60*60*24*100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a cookie array. This is from the manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

```
<?php
// set the cookies
setcookie("cookie[three]", "cookiethree");
setcookie("cookie[two]", "cookietwo");
setcookie("cookie[one]", "cookieone");

// after the page reloads, print them out
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    foreach ($_COOKIE['cookie'] as $name => $value) {
        $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
        echo "$name : $value <br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```